# Is it possible to develop an application that behaves like the Charms Sidebar of Windows 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

Having always made "simple" windows forms I was always content with the traditional windows, I wondered if it was also possible to create an application that would behave like the old Charms Sidebar of Windows 8.
As a reminder, you had to put your mouse in the upper or lower right corner to display the different shortcuts (see the image below).

[Windows 8 charms sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyZqg.png)

I would like to reproduce this same behaviour.
Is this possible? If so, how would you go about making this type of application?

Comment: Why not use the OS's features instead? UWP and now MAUI allow using "charms" even though the UI is no longer the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought it should be possible with UWP but I never saw how it was possible to use Charms. Do you know of any documentation that talks about this? Because my Google searches don't give me anything about it...

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Metro related applications and UI uses a undocumented window "band" feature that normal applications cannot use. All a normal application can do is to set itself as always on top.

Use a low-level mouse [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) to detect cursor movement and check if it is in your "hot area".

Performing the charm bar actions can probably be performed by emulating the Win+... hotkeys with `SendInput`...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is indeed one of my first ideas, but I imagined that the windows api was able to provide a way to achieve this.

Comment: A way to provide what? What is missing?